# rails deleted public/index.html, yet it still appears as default, ignoring root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

This is probably something silly, but I have assuredly deleted the default public/index.html file after having named a root route. Here is my config/routes.rb:

```
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do    
  root to: 'static_pages#home'    
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'    
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'    
  resources :microposts    
  resources :users    
end
```

Simply working on the Rails Tutorial, and this happens. The root definitely exists, as the `root_path` variable gets created and used in a rspec test. The default page still shows up, and I have no idea why... it should have nothing to go off of? Is this a problem with the rails server itself? Something maybe I need to reset/reconfigure with it after deleting the index.html file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you still see the index.html? or is localhost:3000 just not going to: static_pages#home? If the latter...restart your server.

Comment: This could also be a caching issue of your browser.

Comment: @nathanvda It was the browser cache. Dunno why I didn't think of that right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the server, and removing it from version control (if its in production mode that it's there.)

```
$ ^C
$ rails server
```

Using git:

```
$ git rm public/index.html
# re-deploy
```